# chrome extension not work after load new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I developed a chrome extension which generates a custom message for me from skype on clicking it. It works fine on page load and when I scroll down and load more connection to send message extension stop work on it.

```
{
   "name": "Page Redder",
   "description": "Make the current page red",
   "version": "2.0",
   "content_scripts": [   
     { 
       "run_at" :"document_end",
       "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
       "js": ["jquery.js","script.js"]
     } 
   ],
   "permissions": [
      "activeTab"
   ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Make this page red"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

jquery file

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.mn-person-card__person-btn-ext').click(function(){

            var name = $(this).attr('aria-label');

            name = name.replace("Send message to ","");
            var dummyContent = "Hello " + name + ", \n\nThanks for staying connected with me on LinkedIn.";

            $('body').append("<textarea id='absdfjalskjdf'></textarea>");
            document.getElementById('absdfjalskjdf').innerHTML = dummyContent;
            var dummy =$('#absdfjalskjdf').select()
            document.execCommand("Copy");

            $('#absdfjalskjdf').remove();
        });
    });


    $(document).on('change', function(){
        $('.mn-person-card__person-btn-ext').click(function(){

            alert("asldfkjaldfj");
            var name = $(this).attr('aria-label');

            name = name.replace("Send message to ","");
            var dummyContent = "Hello " + name + ", \n\nThanks for staying connected with me on LinkedIn.";

            $('body').append("<textarea id='absdfjalskjdf'></textarea>");
            document.getElementById('absdfjalskjdf').innerHTML = dummyContent;
            var dummy =$('#absdfjalskjdf').select()
            document.execCommand("Copy");

            $('#absdfjalskjdf').remove();
        });
    });
```

When I open all my connection, first loaded connections are work successfully but when load some more connections that time it stop to work. Please help me to make it possible.

Comment: That's an AJAX-driven site which adds content dynamically but your listener is attached only to the elements that were present initially. Usually fixed by switching to *event delegation*.

Comment: can you please explain me a bit more.